# Typescript: make one of two properties optional

Tags: typescript

I have an interface like this:

```
export interface Picture {
  id?: string;
  src?: string;
  width: number;
  height: number;
}
```

I want the model to have value for at least one of the `id` or `src` property. Is there a way to specify that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types) to accomplish your task:

```js
type PictureBase = {
  width: number;
  height: number;
}

export type Picture = ({ id: string } | { src: string }) & PictureBase;
```

See also this article on [discriminated unions](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/discriminated-unions.html)

Comment: no this is a feature of typescript, sometimes also refered to as discrimnated union. The union in this case specifies, that it is *either* `{ id: string }` OR `{ src: string}`

Comment: these things are just types... so no actual data will be stored... not sure what you are refering to...

Comment: we are still in the typescript world. The types will be gone after the compilation step. These types are just a tool for developers, as the code will run as _javascript_...

Comment: the difference being that Java actually requires the types during runtime, where as javascript is dynamically typed.

Comment: Wow, what a lot of nonsense @RobertHarvey. Thanks for your egotistical and totally unhelpful contribution.

Comment: @jmadelaine: FTFY

Answer (score 1):

You can extend those interfaces.

```
interface BasePicture {
  width: number;
  height: number;
}

interface IdPicture extends BasePicture {
  id: string;
}

interface SrcPicture extends BasePicture {
  src: string;
}

export type Picture = IdPicture | SrcPicture;
```